# Data Doesn't Show Up Using ASP.NET MVC Angular

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, angular7

I am trying to learn `Angular` and have basics to start with. I've successfully installed `Angular` in `ASP.NET Core` project without using the default template in visual studio 2017 and run the project with success as well. Here I used `C#` API to get data (The same thing I used to get database data that shows up perfectly), something as follow:

```
public List<string> Get()
{
   return new List<string>() { "Hello World 1!", "Hello World 2!" }; 
}
```

Then finally in `Angular`, I did the below that worked perfectly:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  public values: string[];

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.http.get('/api/values').subscribe(result => { //Calling the API here and values actually is the controller name
      this.values = result.json() as string[];
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
}
```

So my plan is to try the same thing in `ASP.NET MVC` project where again I was successful to install as well run the project. Unfortunately I am unable to return database data in the same way that I tried with API. Say there is a controller **Dashboard** and a method **GetPersons()**. So I wrote the below in the controller:

```
public class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}

[HttpGet]
public List<Person> GetPersons()
{
    List<Person> aLst = new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person() { name = "John", address = "On Earth" },
        new Person() { name = "Jack", address = "On Earth" }
    };

    return aLst;
}
```

In the front-end, I used `Angular` to return the data in the same way as above:

```
public values: object[];

constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.http.get('/Dashboard/GetPersons').subscribe(result => { //Calling the API here
      this.values = result.json() as object[];
   }, error => console.error(error));
}
```

Unfortunately this didn't work and when I tried to debug with the browser's inspect element, the request seems to be not working I mean it's unable to make `http` request with the url written - **/Dashboard/GetPerons**. So does it require anything else to make `Angular` work in the `ASP.NET MVC` project?

**N.B** - In the front-end, I called the `Angular` API as follows:

```
<tr *ngFor="let value of values">
  <td>{{ value.name }}</td>
</tr>
```

**Update - 1** - When I debug with the browser's inspect elemen, I get the following error message:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: missing protocol/domain in api url?

Comment: how is the route(`/Dashboard/GetPersons`) being mapped in your C# api?

Comment: See my updated post @KiraAG. The route is mapped like this - `Controller/Action/id` for the default `ASP.NET MVC` app.

Comment: You can see my updated post @xyz. Any way that I can make it work?

Comment: angular and asp.net mvc both have same url?

Comment: I am bit confused here @Harshit Tailor. It worked perfectly for `ASP.NET Core`. Do I require to include anything more for the routing both `ASP.NET MVC` and `Angular`?

Comment: what is url of your angular application and mvc application?

Comment: if both have different url then you have to add mvc application path  like 'http://localhost:65897/Dashboard/GetPersons'

Comment: i think the problem could be in json parsing., can you put console.log in both next() and error() inside subscribe and let us know which is getting logged?

Comment: Can you also add Startup::Configure method?

Comment: Where should I add that @yurzui?

Comment: To your question

Comment: I was able to make it work and let know if there is any better way to improve it @yurzui. See the posted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally sorted. Basically my issue was - I was returning a `C#` list of objects that the Angular service was unable to interpret. So I just converted the list into `jSon` using `jSon` serialization as follows and finally made it work:

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetPersons()
{
    List<Person> aLst = new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person() { name = "John", address = "On Earth" },
        new Person() { name = "Jack", address = "On Earth" }
    };

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(aLst);
}
```

**N.B**: If any issue faced converting the list to jSon, just run this command to get the package installed from nuget -

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

When used `ASP.NET Core` project using API controller, the `jSon` conversion wasn't required actually in the controller and it was like the below:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    ECommerceContext db = new ECommerceContext(); //Db context

    // GET: api/<controller>
    [HttpGet]
    public List<Products> Get() //Here it didn't require to convert the C# list into jSon
    {
      return GetProducts(); //Get list of products from database
    }

    public List<Products> GetProducts()
    {
      List<Products> result = (from c in db.Products
                               select new Products
                               {
                                 ProductId = c.ProductId, ProductName = c.ProductName
                               }).ToList();

      return result;
    }
}
```

Finally in the `Angular` service, just used the below:

```
public values: object[];

constructor(private http: Http) {
  this.http.get('/api/values').subscribe(result => {
    this.values = result.json() as object[];
    }, error => console.error(error));
}
```